# Is this a bug in Database System Concepts 6th edition-Figure 11.11 Querying a B+-tree.-procedure printAll(value V)?

Tags: database, algorithm, b-plus-tree

In Database System Concepts, 6<sup>th</sup> edition, chapter 11, in "Figure 11.11 Querying a B+-tree.", there is a `procedure printAll(value V)`. It is used to print all records with search key value *V* (there can be duplicates). It calls `find(V)`, which returns the first leaf node that has key *V*, and the first index *i* in that leaf that has that key.

Why doesn't the code include `Set i = 1` when `i > number of keys in L`?

**procedure** printAll(*value V*)
    /* prints all records with search key value *V* */
    Set done = false;
    Set (*L,i*) = find(*V*);
    **if** ((*L,i*) is null) **return**
    **repeat**
        **repeat**
            Print record pointed to by *L.P<sub>i</sub>*
            Set *i* = *i* + 1
        **until** (*i* > number of keys in *L* **or** *L.K<sub>i</sub>* > *V*)
        **if** (*i* > number of keys in *L*)
            **then** *L* = *L.P<sub>n</sub>* // No need to set *i* to 1?
            **else** Set done = true;
    **until** (done or *L* is null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right. `i` needs to be reset to 1 when moving to the next leaf in the B+ tree.

It is also not corrected in the ["Errata and Updates For Database System Concepts, 6<sup>th</sup> Edition"](https://www.db-book.com/db6/errata-dir/errata-part3.pdf)

There is a C++ implementation [on github](https://github.com/lishichengyan/BPlusTree/blob/master/BPlusTree.cpp), inspired by this book, which *does* reset *i* as it should have been. Of course, in C++ indexes are zero-based:

```cpp
void BPlusTree::printAll(string v) {
    //
    // B+ tree described in the book may contain duplicate keys
    // printAl prints all the records with key v
    // but here I modified it to print all records with key >= v
    //
    bool done = false;
    auto pair = find(v);
    auto p = pair.first;
    auto i = pair.second;
    if (i == -1) {  // not found
        cout << "no such record" << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "i is " << i << endl;
    while (!done and p != NULL) {
         // be careful with special cases, may encounter NULL pointer, size is also a problem (#pointer = #key + 1)
        for (; (i < p->_ptrs.size() && i < p->_keys.size() && v <= p->_keys[i]) or (i == p->_keys.size()); i++) {
            if (p->_ptrs[i] == NULL) {
                continue;
            }
            cout << "record: " << *reinterpret_cast<int*>(p->_ptrs[i]) << endl;
        }
        if (i >= _num_of_keys(p)) {
            p = p->_next;  // move to next leaf node
            i = 0;  // adjust i
        }
        else {
            done = true;
        }
    }
}
```